# How to get text of an object of type View

Tags: android, view

Agnostically, we are recognizing the currently showing layout without knowing its name, then we are traversing through all the views in the layout to get their ids using

```
id = container.getChildAt(i).getId()
```

then converting the obtaind id to a View using

```
view = findViewById(id)
```

then we are trying to get the text assigned to that view using

```
view.getText()
```

but '.getText' method is not defined on objects of type View

please let mek know to get the text assigned to an object of type View.

Comment: what do you mean under the name if a layout or the View? If you mean `R.id.some_name` - it is not a name existing in runtime - it is `static int` Java identifier, existing only int source code.
`getText()` - is getter for property of instances of certain class that have this property. Layout doesn't have such

Answer (score 2):

You can check the type of `View` using `instanceof` and cast to `TextView` and get value.

Example:

```
    if (view instanceof Textview)
    {
      ((TextView)view).getText();
    } else if (view instanceof EditText)
   {
     ((EditText)view).getText();
   }
```

Instead of getting ids and finding views using `findViewById(id)` you can use the child from container.

i.e. you can do like this

```
if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
{
....
}
```

Comment: ok..but i am not sure if the view i am getting is a TextView or Edittext or exactly what?

Comment: Eg. instanceof EditText